# Making an in-app settings page (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, application-settings

I am making an app which needs a settings page. Which will be a different class, so how do I pass data from one class to the other? For example: There is a UISwitch on the settings page, and I need to see what option the user selected for another class.

Thanks.

Comment: I would highly recommend using InAppSettings to make the settings screen for you: http://bitbucket.org/keegan3d/inappsettings/wiki/Home It uses NSUserDefaults to save the data and simply reads your Settings.bundle file.

Answer (score 3):

On your settings page, use the following code to synchronize your settings -

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject: data forKey: @""]; // The forKey is the name of the setting you're going to sync
[defaults synchronize];
```

And to get the value of the setting in your other controllers, use the following -

```
NSString *settingValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @""]; // The objectForKey is the name of the setting you're getting the value for.
```

Hope this helps you!